# failed to resolve me.answershahriar:calligrapher:4.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to create a calculator.  I want to add a library to add font.
so I added

```
compile 'me.answershahriar:calligraper:4.0'
```

but I got the following error :

> failed to resolve 'me.answershahriar:calligraper:4.0

I am using android studio 2.2 and compilesdk version 28

gradle version = 2.14.1

Answer (score 0):

try    `'implementation'me.answershahriar:calligraper:4.0'`

and try to get the lastest version of andriod studio,and search if **4.0** is the lastest version library and in your question the library is **1.0**..

Comment: I tried it but I got another error      {could not find method implementation() for argument [me.answershahriar.calligrapher:4.0]}

Comment: comment the error here or ask a new question if the error is too long and comment the link here

Comment: whats the version of your gradle?

Comment: try to upgrage your andriod studio but first you can try to use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`